# Cannot bring up UIView on different tab with Storyboard

Tags: ios, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller, segue

I created a storyboard for my app which contains the following:

1. Initial view controller on my storyboard is a Tab Bar Controller (let's call it myTabCtrlr)
2. myTabCtrlr has forward segues pointing to several other controllers:
   a. First segue points to a custom UIViewController (let's call it vc1) on which I create an interactive UIView (let's call it popview1) which is initially hidden. There's a button (let's call it showPopView1) on vc1's view which when clicked would show popview1
   b. Second segue points to a navigation controller, which embeds a view controller with 3 buttons, each pointing to an (end) controller.
   c. Third segue points to another navigation controller with a similar setup as (b)

On several of these (end) controllers, there's a button similar to vc1's showPopView1 that when tapped, I'd like to switch back to vc1 and programmatically bring up popview1, which I'm doing as follows (but it's not working):

```
myTabCtrlr.selectedIndex = 0;
//I get a handle to vc1 then
vc1.popview1.hidden = NO;
```

When I do that, it goes back to the first tab and shows vc1 view (which is good) but it does not show popview1. I tried many different ways to do it but no luck.

Note that if I'm actually on vc1 and I tap the showPopView1 button, then popview1 comes up normally.
Does anybody know why that is the case? This only started after I transitioned to using storyboard. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After spending hours looking at various ways to solve this problem, and focusing on reverse segues and similar methods, I was able to solve it using a totally different method.. I wanted to share this with others so nobody has to waste so much of their time (although I noticed slow response to my post. Maybe I didn't make the subject attractive enough :).. 
It's a really simple solution, but quite effective. I used a Singleton pattern object. When coming from the rest of the tabs, I set a flag in the singleton that vc1 checks in its viewWillAppear method, shows popview1, and immediately resets the flag.. works like a charm!